# Pandas: Column from Match without Merge

Tags: python, pandas

I need to populate a column based on a match in a different column.

DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1000, 'Jerry', 'BR1','BR1'], 
                             [1001, 'Sal', 'BR2', 'BR1'], 
                             [1002, 'Buck', 'BR3', 'BR2'],
                             [1003, 'Perry','BR4','BR1']]),
                   columns=['ID', 'Name', 'Branch', 'Member of'])
```

I need to create a "bosses" column.

- A boss is defined as the `Name` returned after matching `Member of` to some field in column `Branch`.

I can do it this way:

```
df_bosses = df[['Name', 'Branch']].copy()
df_bosses.rename(columns={'Name':'Boss'},inplace=True)
df.merge(df_bosses, how="left", left_on="Member of", right_on="Branch")
```

This gets me where I want to be -- just need to rename a column and drop another.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Beside the point, but why are you using NumPy array? It doesn't add anything AFAIK, and it'll make the integer column `object` instead of `int64`, which you could do in other  clearer ways if needed.

Comment: Yeah, @EA you could omit the `np.array(` part entirely, and just use lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Boss'] = df['Member of'].map(df.set_index('Branch')['Name'])
```

Output:

```
>>> df
     ID   Name Branch Member of   Boss
0  1000  Jerry    BR1       BR1  Jerry
1  1001    Sal    BR2       BR1  Jerry
2  1002   Buck    BR3       BR2    Sal
3  1003  Perry    BR4       BR1  Jerry
```

Comment: What if `Member of` contains a blank string or `NaN`?

Comment: Anything in `Member of` that isn't in `Branch` will come out as NaN in `Boss`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I will do `replace`

```
df['new'] = df['Member of'].replace(df.set_index('Branch')['Name'])
df
     ID   Name Branch Member of    new
0  1000  Jerry    BR1       BR1  Jerry
1  1001    Sal    BR2       BR1  Jerry
2  1002   Buck    BR3       BR2    Sal
3  1003  Perry    BR4       BR1  Jerry
```